# How to set "DockIconImage" in JavaFX Application

Tags: javafx

I am using below javaFX code to set the application icon-

`stage.getIcons().add(new Image("images/Logo.png"));`

above code is working for Windows OS but not working for macOS.

Please help..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have used below code and Yes!!! it is working.. :)

```
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC) {
    URL iconURL = MainStart.class.getResource("/images/Logo.png");
    java.awt.Image image = new ImageIcon(iconURL).getImage();
    com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication().setDockIconImage(image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A dock icon for the Mac can only be set via the packager tool. Here is a nice tutorial which describes the process.
[Packaging](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/)

Comment: Thanks @mipa for the answer, I found the different code(Commented in the answer) which is just a 3 lines of java code and It is looking simple.

Comment: You are right. I've forgotten that solution although I once used that myself. I am getting old :-(